# How to know if an app doesn't work because my phone doesn't support or it's just the app's fault?

Tags: samsung, android-10, crashes, crash-reports

When the internal storage (not the SD Card) in my phone is almost full, sometimes it makes some apps failed to be installed, but they will be able to be installed after I free up some space.

I installed three different apps today and they are from different developers, but they have the very similar behaviour when they're crashed. So, I concluded that my phone might have been broken or something. The apps can be normally accessed, but they will crash and force closed, the errors can't also be reported, I'm not sure.  I don't know whether my phone doesn't support the apps or it's just the apps that don't function well. I bought the phone 7 months ago, and I think it's unlikely that it's broken already.

How to know if it has something to do with the storage or some settings I don't understand perhaps? The app version, minimun SDK, minimum or maximum android requirements or whatever.

Comment: You would want to look at bugreport (you have to create it first) or in the output of logcat. Both are not meant to be understood by *end users* though.

Comment: *"... it makes some apps failed to be installed ..."* and *"... when they're crashed ..."* are two different problems. Do they fail to install or crash after installation? For the former issue do `adb install` to get the exact error. For the latter do `adb logcat` when the app crashes.

Comment: I'd assume this is about [the Stack Exchange app that you mentioned in your next question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/247814/44325). Yes, I checked the log using logcat and found that the combination of the library used in the app and the OS version made this crash.

Comment: @AndrewT. This question is 2 days ago before updating my phone. The app that I'm talking about is different. I was installing languages learning apps but they're not too important I think. Whilst my next question i.e. today's question is about the app version of Stack Exchange and I'm a bit sentimental, so I wish someone would tell me if there's anything I could do to run the app perfectly.